# Different types of regular expression testers

Tags: regex

I am testing an Rstudio regex on regex101.com: `([0-9]+([+\\-\\*\/]+[0-9]+){1,})` works fine with my test data:

```
1/3
1+2
1/3
10*2
10*8/3
```

However when I put that regex into Rstudio it freaks out because `\/` is not a valid escape character (but this was required for the regex101.com to work)

What is the difference between the ways regex is being evaluated in the two programs?

**Justification for re-opening:**

This question is not intended to deal with a specific regex (I included the one above just as an example).

I have never see an answer to the *actual question* asked in this post. Although there are many specific regex questions this is intended to be more of a general difference between regex types question (eg Perl regex vs Notepad++).

Comment: use this `([0-9]+([+\\-\\*/]+[0-9]+){1,})`, In R, yu just need to double escape the backslash.

Comment: In addition, speaking of differences: if you want to use pcre regexes, which is the default on regex101.com, you may want to set `perl=TRUE` in `grep` or `sub` or whatever you use in R.

Comment: I think this is a good question exposing the backslashing issue and should not be considered a mere typo.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik: Then please hit *Reopen*.